# NullPointerException at ZipInputStream

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish-3, omnifaces

I have a JSF application (Majorra 2.1.20, PrimeFaces 4.0-SNAPSHOT, OmniFaces 1.4.1, running on Glassfish 3.1.2) that works fine in Firefox, Chrome.  ONLY when running in Internet Explorer do I get this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: in is null
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.<init>(ZipInputStream.java:100)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.<init>(ZipInputStream.java:79)
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ZipDirectoryEntryScanner.<init>(ZipDirectoryEntryScanner.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ClasspathResourceHelper.findLibraryWithZipDirectoryEntryScan(ClasspathResourceHelper.java:204)
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.findLibraryOnClasspathWithZipDirectoryEntryScan(ResourceManager.java:409)
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.doLookup(ResourceManager.java:247)
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.findResource(ResourceManager.java:197)
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:143)
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:123)
at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.createResource(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:96)
at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.createResource(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:96)
at org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.UnmappedResourceHandler.createResource(UnmappedResourceHandler.java:118)
at com.sun.faces.el.ResourceELResolver.getValue(ResourceELResolver.java:136)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHelper$ELEvaluatingInputStream.evaluateExpressionIntoBuffer(ResourceHelper.java:791)
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHelper$ELEvaluatingInputStream.readExpressionIntoBufferAndEvaluateIntoBuffer(ResourceHelper.java:722)
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHelper$ELEvaluatingInputStream.read(ResourceHelper.java:690)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:179)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
at java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Channels.java:385)
at org.omnifaces.util.Utils.stream(Utils.java:215)
at org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.UnmappedResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(UnmappedResourceHandler.java:196)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:591)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.VirtualServerPipeline.invoke(VirtualServerPipeline.java:131)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:328)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I am at a lost.  I cannot seem to understand why this would only happen in IE and not in other browsers.

Any help to resolve this would be appreciated.  An explanation to help understand this would also be very welcome (The more you know!)

#### Update :

I am now getting this error in Chrome as well.  Still looking into this.

#### Update 2 :

<strike>I've found the source of this problem (not cause, but faulty code).  This in my css sheet :</strike>

```css
a.map_sms:hover {
background: #3E9945 url("#{resource['templateImages/map:map_sms.png']}")
    no-repeat;
}
```

is causing the error.  Removing this solves it.  This error started showing up when upgraded to PrimeFaces 4.0, never before.  Luckily this was legacy code that I just removed and the error is no longer showing up.

#### Update 3

What I though was the solution to fixing this error was definitely not it.  Still getting it, back to the drawing board.

#### Update 4

Seems like update 2 was right.  Found another faulty css in the likes.  Lots of time spent finding this here.  Still unsure of the reason for the error - which was non-existant before upgrading to PrimeFaces 4.

#### Update 5

After thinking I had fixed this for good, it came back when in Eclipse I liked 2 projects together (adding a second project on the build path).  Not sure if this directs to any leads.

Comment: Can you show some more context? On what request this happens, what it should be doing, etc.

Comment: I'd love to, but this is on initial page load.  It queries data from the database, and displays it on a `p:dataTable`.  I'll look into providing a sample of my code, but I'm afraid this will require quite a bit of code for anything to make sense.

Comment: Based on the stack trace, this concerns thus a resource request on a CSS file with EL expressions enclosed. Which one is it? What are the request headers in IE and what are those in others?

Comment: @BalusC It was you you mentioned.  It was a background image I was using in the CSS.  This same error popped in in Chrome as well.  I was able to get rid of this error by clearing the browser cache.  I'm at a lost as to the reasoning behind this (still too little comprehension at this point...)

Comment: Well, I'd guess a race condition in the server's classpath resource management. To start, I'd try upgrading Glassfish.

Comment: @BalusC I've finally upgraded to 3.1.2.2 and am still getting the same error message.  Unfortunately, I don't have the time to test out v4 for our production environment yet.  I'll keep digging into the source of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be hitting this issue when your container scans the jar files in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

`ZipDirectoryEntryScanner` is a mojarra class. I would suggest you grab the source and add a log statement in that class to see which file is problematic.

I ran into a similar issue and, in my case, the `WEB-INF/lib` folder contained another folder called `logs` which was causing the exception.

Comment: Deleting that folder got rid of the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I had used Customer.class.getResourceAsStream("fi.png");
instead of Customer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fi.png")
so getting this exception

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem was in the filename path - it contained "**!**" symbol. I've changed the path and problem was solved.